# Problems getting id posted with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to post an id to my ajax.php page with ajax, but unfortunately it doesn't work. More precisely, after sending the id, I load that page and it does not appear there. How can I fix this problem, thank you.

```
$(".connectedSortable li").click(function(){
            $(".connectedSortable li").css('filter', 'grayscale(100%)');
            $(this).css('filter', 'none');
            var id = $(this).attr('data-index');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'assets/standart/ajax.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data:{
                    id: id
                },success:function(){
                    $("#formDuzenle").load('assets/standart/ajax.php');
                }
            })
        })
```

This is my ajax.php document

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "it does not appear there"? As you are posting the data to the route, and do not store it there, it's obvious that a second request of that route yields a different result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two HTTP requests.

First you make a POST request to `ajax.php`. You send an `id` and the PHP script echos it back.

Then, when the request is `success`ful you run a function with makes a GET request to `ajax.php`. You don't send the ID again, and you display the result in `formDuzenle`.

There is nothing in your code which would make PHP remember the data from the first request and send it back to you again for the second request.

---

You should make **one** and only one HTTP request.

Either use **only** `$.ajax` and then do something with the data you get back in the `success` function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'assets/standart/ajax.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {id },
    success: function(data){
        $("#formDuzenle").text(data);
    }
})
```

**or**

Use **only** `$(...).load()` and make it a POST request:

```
$("#formDuzenle").load('assets/standart/ajax.php', { id } );
```